# Posting to Javascript from php without form action

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm working on a child theme that uses ultimate member and redefines some of it's functions. Previously it redefined the follow button and sent the info to a payment form and then the form sent the info to a javascript file. The form is no longer used so we are trying to send the info directly to a javascript file and I haven't worked with php in awhile so I'm a little lost. The only options I find are form action and method post which aren't working, 
The function is

```
        <div class="um-followers-btn">
            <?php


            if (in_array("um_customer", $res->roles)) {
                $nav_link =    UM  ()->permalinks()->get_current_url(get_option('permalink_structure'));
                $nav_link = remove_query_arg('um_action', $nav_link);
                $nav_link = remove_query_arg('subnav', $nav_link);
                $nav_link = add_query_arg('profiletab', $id, $nav_link);

And previously the trigger was 

  echo '<a href="" id="cm_follow_button" data-toggle="modal" data-    target="#payment_modal" class="um-button" >Follow</a>';
```

Obviously this doesn't work so any help would be appreciated.

Apologies, the echo puts forth a "follow" button, what the button appears but what I"m trying to accomplish is for the values, such as user1 and user2 to go to another php file which inserts them into the database and changes the button to request sent this is allhandled in the other php file by the previous team, I'm having trouble sending it there, the previous method was going to a javascript file from the last line above,  this line produced the button which when pressed called forth a php form that took payment info, and then sent that to a js form which in turn took theinfo fand verified the payment format, changed the "follow" to "Follow request sent"  and sent the rest to a php form that as I said,  put the ifo in the mysql database and gave the 2nd user the option of accepting the follow request. Ultimate Member doesn't offer this option which is why it was modified in a child theme like this. We aren't processing payment like this we just want the button to send the info to the php form and I'm having that issue with doing it, via this button. I hope that helps

Comment: Please be slightly clearer on what you are exactly trying to accomplish, other than that, good question!

Comment: I'm trying to post the information such as the current user name and the user they are trying to post the information to another php file that will take it and insert it into a database, should be userid1 userid2 and request the js currently takes the info and sends it to the php I"d like to omit that part becuase it does other thing that we don't use now. So trying to send info to the next php by way of the echo button.